# Custom 404 page in Magento

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

I know you can create and customize 404 pages directly within the Magento backend. However, I am wanting to completely use my own 404 customized page and was wondering how to do this.

I have created a 404.html file and added it in the root of my magento installation. However, I don't see in the .htaccess file how magento currently is redirecting the 404 to the CMS 404 page. How can I have it redirect to my custom 404 html file instead without causing some sort of never ending redirect loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Yah I already knew that but it appears that there is no work around. I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

404 page set from backend
System>Configuration>General>Web>Default Pages > YOU CAN FIND CMS No Route Page which will be default Magento CMS PAGE 404

for custom 404 page you have to create new cms page and you have to call your CUSTOM.phtml file in your new cms page after then go to the

System>Configuration>General>Web>Default Pages >CMS No Route Page > you can see your cms page and set your page as 404 page

[image: path]

Comment: Thanks, however as previously stated, I am not wanting to use Magento for that at all. I want to use my own custom 404.html file that will look nothing like my store.

Comment: i think its  not possible to call without using of magento,,

Answer (score 2):

I know it is quite an old question, but I've found the answer in this tutorial: http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages

It explain very well how to make really custom 404 error page.